# Pass cookie from JNLP to JAVAWS to download protected resources

Tags: java, cookies, java-web-start, jnlp, java-ws

I have a setup where I obtain protected JNLP via browser, and JNLP saves the authentication cookie as a property. Then javaws is run with the jnlp file. The jnlp requires protected resources, so I need to pass the authentication cookie to the javaws process, so it can use it when downloading the resources... How can I pass the auth cookie to javaws process?

I've checked all parameters available to javaws and JNLP but I couldnt find how this can be done.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found solution. Java Web Start uses the same cookie store as Internet Explorer - see comments in [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6428486) to see how IE persistent cookies are harvested by JavaWebStart application.

To get this to work, I developed following:

1. JNLP and jars are protected
2. Access JNLP via IE - this will redirect you to login page where you log in and obtain authentication cookies
3. In your Web server have a servlet that intercepts the authentication cookie, make it persistent and add it to response

   ```
   public class CookieServlet extends org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController {
   ...
       protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(final HttpServletRequest req,
                                            final HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
           ....
           Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
           String session = null;
           if (cookies != null) {
               for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                   if (cookie.getName().equals("AUTHSESSION")) {
                       session = cookie.getValue();
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }


           if(null!=session) {
               Cookie cookie = new Cookie("AUTHSESSION", session);
               cookie.setMaxAge(<specify cookie age>);
               resp.addCookie(cookie);
           }
           ...
       }
   ```
4. Now launch your jnlp via cmd.exe - you can access the resources without issues as it harvests cookies from IE cookie store

Note: if your authentication supports auth session token being passed as a parameter then you could also extend jnlp "jar" tag to include the AUTHSESSION value i.e.

```
<jar href="your_jar.jar?AUTHSESSION=<session value>"/>
```

For us this is not the case and the auth session must be provided as a cookie.

Comment: This is actually working currently, it's not in prod system yet as we have some other unrelated issues to iron out (deploying WS app with custom JRE...) but so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is a dynamically created JNLP from your server which includes the cookie (or even better a ticket?) as `<parameter>`. This article helped me a lot http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160423141428/http://portal.krypthonas.de/2010/10/11/passing-dynamically-parameters-to-a-java-web-start-app-jnlp/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this however will not work. I can pass in parameters dynamically, this is not a problem (either set them as a property or into main method). The issue is the jars I am requesting are protected hence any attempt to fetch them causes redirect (to login page) and java WS fails with "illegal URL redirect" error.

Comment: You mean to downlaod the JavaWebStart JAR itselfe you need to be authenticated? Why not place the JAR within the public resource folder of the web server where no authentication is required?

Comment: Correct. We could just place the jars in a public domain, but we want to have restrictions over who can access our codebase, hence the jars are protected too - along with the JNLP. We do not want to introduce additional authentication factor at Apache level to the authentication cookies that protect the jars as that creates additional burden when onboarding clients.

Comment: Okay this is beyond my knowledge. Good luck!